# Как поместить обычное сообщения в Embed ? Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord

у меня есть код, который отправляет обычное сообщение, вот он :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { QuickDB } = require('quick.db')

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'Посмотреть команды сервера',
    options: [],
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('тут напишу команды');
    },
};
```

как сделать чтобы от отправлял сообщение в ембеде[image: вот так же]